# Распасить строки json с одинаковыми ключами

Tags: javascript, json

Имеется json файл на сервере в который прилетают клиентские данные в формате json, и потом по нажатии кнопочки на сайте должны вывестись все данные из этого файла. Вопрос в том как распарсить несколько строк в которых одинаковые ключи , но разные значения,при помощи js. У меня все идет в одну строку, при использовании JSON.parse(), получаю "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 110".

`{"Email":"banan03112000@gmail.com","Socials":"vk.com/example","Dates":"12.02.2020","Surname":"minaleeva","Name":"vanina"}{"Email":"banan03112000@gmail.com", ...(итд)}`

Вот так выглядит Json.

Comment: Это не json. Подозреваю, что вам нужно эти данные разбить на строки и парсить каждую строку отдельно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы контролируете клиентский код, его нужно исправить, потому что формально это не JSON (не хватает запятых на границах объектов (между фигурными скобками) и нет окружающих это всё квадратных скобок массива). Если не контролируете, можно попробовать разделить по границам фигурных скобок и превратить это в массив объектов. Но это хрупкий путь, так как входные данные непредсказуемы.

```js
const input = '{"Email":"banan03112000@gmail.com","Socials":"vk.com/example","Dates":"12.02.2020","Surname":"minaleeva","Name":"vanina"}{"Email":"banan03112000@gmail.com"}';

const array = input.split(/(?<=\})(?=\{)/).map(string => JSON.parse(string));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, после преобразования в массив json ошибки ушли. Теперь вопрос в том как мне правильно распарсить этот массив json в массив объектов и последовательно выводить каждый объект.

Comment: @xantin Так в моём примере на выходе уже получается массив объектов. Можете перебрать массив при помощи цикла [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) или через метод [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).